# Programmatically reference folder or file from Eclipse product directory

Tags: java, eclipse, rcp

I'm creating an Eclipse RCP product that will have a /bin directory in the top level folder that will contain some file. What's the best approach for programmatically getting to the /bin location?

Product directory:

[image: Product directory]

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In a plugin use `Platform.getInstallLocation` to get the installation directory location:

```
URL installURL = Platform.getInstallLocation().getURL();

String path = URIUtil.toURI(installURL).toASCIIString();
```

Both `Platform` and `URIUtil` are in the `org.eclipse.core.runtime` package / plugin.